# Why is Google Bot Crawling non-existent CSS file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-crawler, asset-pipeline, googlebot

Google Bot Crawler is consistently trying to crawl CSS files that do not exist on my site in production.

It asks for:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/assets/index-d45678283d4ab9905c3538184826e599.css
```

This exact file name does not exist in production (there is a slightly different file name in production).

However, the CSS file that it is requesting does exist in development at:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/index-d45678283d4ab9905c3538184826e599.css
```

I'm not sure why it is asking for this file.

I use Capistrano (load "deploy/assets") to precompile my assets before deploying to production.

Right now, I just block this file in robots.txt but the css file that it requests changes after every deployment.

Why does GoogleBot want to crawl this file that doesn't exist in production site? How do I stop it?

Answer (score 3):

GoogleBot is probably seeing one of two things:

- It sees that file on your site somewhere where it has been referenced incorrectly - I.E. old code builds. I would search your live site (bundled) for the file.
- It remembers that file from a previous build, and is trying to check it for updates.

It puzzles me that it would not ignore it after a 404 response from your server, however, the inner workings of Google's software are a black box; there's no true way to tell why it does what it does.

That said, they offer the [Webmaster Tools Panel](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) that allows you to do some customization of their indexing etc.

Comment: I don't reference that file anywhere in my code. I think that it is probably remembering it from a previous build and is checking for updates. But it's just weird because the way Rails compiles this CSS, it will always append a different random sequence to my index.css file name so interested to see if anyone else sees this problem.

Comment: Have you checked the webmaster tools panel?

Comment: It still happens from time to time even though I have uploaded a sitemap.xml to my root folder

Comment: I evaluated just blocking all CSS and JS from googlebot, but apparently you aren't supposed to do that: https://yoast.com/dont-block-css-and-js-files/

Comment: We're seeing the same behavior too, Googlebot is trying to load old CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to develop the idea of Christian Stewart. I see the following situations:

- If you use a cache system on your server (e.g: wordpress cache plugin), old webpages of your website may still contain URLs to your old CSS file.
- If you use a CDN with a cache like Cloudflare, and if it caches your webpage, old pages may still have a URL pointing to your old CSS file.